# Flutter: Add values to a complex map dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

In a map

```
Map test = {};
```

What is the way to add values from textFields onChanged event:

```
onChanged: (value) {  
    // This is the onChanged Method of quantity textField            
    test['$index'] = ? /* This is the V/K 'qty': value */
},
```

I have two more texFields:

```
onChanged: (value) {  
        // This is the onChanged Method of element1 textField            
        test['$index'] = ? /* This is theV/K 'el1': value */
    },
```

And:

```
onChanged: (value) {  
            // This is the onChanged Method of element2 textField           
            test['$index'] = ? /* This is theV/K 'el2': value */
        },
```

This is the final wished map:

```
{
    0: {qty: 100, el1: element1, el2: element2}, 
    1: {qty: 200, el1: element1, el2: element2}, 
    2: {qty: 300, el1: element1, el2: element2}
}
```

Where 0,1,2...N are the indexes

I will forever appreciate any help or advice